# How Can I Pass a Custom Flag to the 'nx angular serve' Command Without Encountering an Error?

Tags: angular, nrwl-nx

I wish to include my custom flag (-t example) when executing the `nx angular serve` command.

However, I encounter an error from `nx` indicating:

> 't' is not found in schema

I intend to intercept this flag within `proxy.mjs` and handle it accordingly.

What steps should I take to pass this argument without encountering an error?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass environment variables to `ng serve` using `ENV t=xxx` where `xxx` is the value you want.

```
ENV t=123 ng serve
```

You can then retrieve the value via `process.env`:

```js
const { t } = process.env;
console.log(t); 

// Logs (string): 123
```

For multiple variables, you just use multiple `ENV` commands:

```bash
# All three ways seem to work:

ENV t=123 ENV u=abc ng serve
ENV t=123 u=abc ng serve
t=123 u=abc ng serve
```

Then logging would be the same:

```js
const { t, u } = process.env;
console.log(t); 
console.log(u); 

// Logs (string): 123
// Logs (string): abc
```

Comment: I prefer to do it using nx command..

Comment: Have you tried with using nx commands? All your doing is setting an environment variable and then running whatever command you want...